# Zend_View::_run(), what does line 106 do?

Tags: php, zend-framework

can someone provide a brief explanation of what this line does:

`include 'zend.view://' . func_get_arg(0);`

What's with the "zend.view://" syntax?  I've never seen a file included like this before.  Appreciate your help, cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a custom [stream](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.stream.php) implementation, probably a [wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php).

> Streams were introduced with PHP 4.3.0 as a way of generalizing file, network, data compression, and other operations which share a common set of functions and uses. In its simplest definition, a stream is a resource object which exhibits streamable behavior. That is, it can be read from or written to in a linear fashion, and may be able to fseek() to an arbitrary locations within the stream.

Take a look around for calls to the `stream_` family of functions, and you'll find where it's declared and exactly what it's doing to the underlying file.

Comment: Charles is correct - in this class' case, the Zend_View stream wrapper allows you to use short_tags in your view scripts without having short_tags turned on. See: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.introduction.html#zend.view.introduction.shortTags

Comment: This feature is not recommended as it is expensive. Use it when you have no other options.

Comment: Hey Charles, leek, and Xerkus, thx a lot for the answers!  Really appreciate it.